# Webpack Define Plugin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, environment-variables

In `webpack.config.js` I have the following:

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({
          'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
          'process.env.FLAG': JSON.stringify('false'),
        }),
        new webpack.DefinePlugin({ 'process.env.BLAH': JSON.stringify('tahtah') }),
    ],
    ...
    ...
}
```

However, when I log `module.exports.plugins` I get the following strange result:

```
[ DefinePlugin {
    definitions: 
     { 'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"development"',
       'process.env.FLAG': '"false"' } },
  DefinePlugin { definitions: { 'process.env.BLAH': '"tahtah"' } } ]
```

Why don't I log the following?

```
[ DefinePlugin {
    definitions: 
     { 'process.env.NODE_ENV': '"development"',
       'process.env.FLAG': '"false"',
       'process.env.BLAH': '"tahtah"' } } ]
```

Comment: Why is the result strange? You are adding two instances of `webpack.DefinePlugin` to the `plugins` array and that is exactly what you are seeing. *"Why don't I log the following:"* Because you are adding *two* elements to the array, not just *one*. *"What can I change to get the above result?"* You already provided the solution to that question. However, is there a specific reason you want it that way?

Comment: OHH --- gotcha.. no nevermind. This makes sense now. I thought there was a bug in the object -- I just read the brackets incorrectly -- you can use your comment as the answer if you want